# Versioning change sets in AWS Codepipeline and Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

A common AWS Cloudformation CodePipeline deploy snippet looks like this:

```
        - Name: CreateChangeSet
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Version: '1'
            Provider: CloudFormation
          Configuration:
            ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
            RoleArn: ...
            StackName: ...
            ChangeSetName: deploy-commit
            TemplatePath: ...
            Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: ...
          RunOrder: 1

        - Name: ExecuteChangeSet
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Provider: CloudFormation
            Version: '1'
          Configuration:
            ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE
            ChangeSetName: deploy-commit
            RoleArn: ..
            StackName: ...
          RunOrder: 2
```

We create a change set and execute. Is there a pattern or way through which we can get a unique `ChangeSetName` for each new release. Cause `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` deletes the previous one and creates a new one with the same name and thus we lost the history.

Comment: Never worked with these specific services, but can't you have Coudbuild output the git and use it as a parameter when calling the CloudFormation template? Then use something like `ChangeSetName: !Sub 'deploy-commit-${ShaCodebuild}'`

Comment: I wish I could do that but not possible. CodeBuild only exports artifacts which are files.

Answer (score 2):

Your source action, either GitHub or CodeCommit, should already has the history of changes. But as per your request, unfortunately, CodePipeline's CloudFormation doesn't support to create change set with different name for every execution. All the possible action mode is listed in the following link and none of them supports creating change set with different name for every execution. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html#w2ab1c13c13b9

One possible approach to meet your need is to write your own custom CloudFormation action type, using either CodeBuild, Lambda invoke or custom action type. You can have your own implementation to call CloudFormation APIs to create change set with new names and deploy the change set. More information about custom action type can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html

Comment: Hey Thank you for your answer. Seems like there is not straight forward way to get what I wanted. Custom action looks interesting and I think will be worth the  exploration.

Comment: Custom actions and lambdas seem to be too much work. I guess I will have to live with my question.